# Search from a list of hyperlink if the file exist then select the path as directory

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find search from a list of hyperlink in the column D and if the folder exist in the link then select the link as copy path directory so the macro can open the file and copy one of the sheet in it.

I use the long way by repeating the code, how can it be done in the shorter way?

```
If FileFolderExists(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Config").Range("D2")) Then

    CopyFromDirPathFile = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Config").Range("D2")
'
'
'
'
'
end sub
```

I repeat until D8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this without reapeating the code, the cleanest way is by using a loop. ie, loop through each cell in range "D" until you get to the cell where you want to stop, in this case "D8".

You will have to debug this code yourself as I don't know if your fuction is working or not.

```
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rng As Range
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Config")
    For Each rng In ws.Range("D2:D8")
       If FileFolderExists(rng) Then
          CopyFromDirPathFile = rng
       End If
    Next rng
```